# Xcode continuous integration didn't complete as expected

Tags: ios, xcode, build, continuous-integration, bots

I am trying to use Xcode continuous integration bots with a project, but I am unable to get it working or to know what's wrong.

It is probably a bug with Xcode 6.1, sadly the error message is not very helpful:
[image: Build Service Error The integration didn't complete as expected]

Here is the full error description obtained on client side:

```
Bot Issue: error. Build Service Error.
Issue: The integration didn't complete as expected..
Integration Number: 6.
Integration URL: https://iMac-OS-X-Server.local/xcode/bots/4E1F039/integrations
Description: The integration didn't complete as expected..
```

On server side I could get the following crash backtrace:

```
Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fb896933a40 :: NSOperation 0x7fb8930a4ee0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a1bc64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff872816de objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a1bc4fd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a179e5d mutateError + 221
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b970e31 -[NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:] + 142
5   DVTSourceControl                    0x000000010a6a7e69 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspace workingCopyForRemoteRepository:inBlueprint:] + 733
6   DVTSourceControl                    0x000000010a6a81b2 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspace historySinceRevisionedBlueprint:maximumLogItems:completionBlock:] + 360
7   xcsbuildd                           0x000000010a4ef360 __47-[XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep saveCommitHistory]_block_invoke + 1014
8   xcsbuildd                           0x000000010a4f97ec -[XCSIntegrationStep performSynchronousBlock:] + 314
9   xcsbuildd                           0x000000010a4eef41 -[XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep saveCommitHistory] + 146
10  xcsbuildd                           0x000000010a4ebe84 __47-[XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep enqueueOperations]_block_invoke116 + 21
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8ba1e2e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
12  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b90a905 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 97
13  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b8e959c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
14  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b8e91a3 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff81550c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff81554365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff81555ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff815536b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff81561fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8506f6cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8506d4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82932132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b94e7ae -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 131
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ba1ed14 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 254
3   xcsbuildd                       0x000000010a4db3cb -[XCSIntegrationExecutor execute] + 686
4   xcsbuildd                       0x000000010a4f7ead -[XCSBuildWatcher executeIntegration:] + 232
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff81555323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff81550c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8155ccbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a10fc59 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a0cc2ef __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a0cb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b94bab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
12  xcsbuildd                       0x000000010a4d0867 main + 785
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff833855c9 start + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and what ended up happening was that a background process caused the machine to run out of memory. Restarting the machine fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem and I solved restarting the machine. But, after I integrated once (after restarting), the error still appear during next integrations, so I have to restart the machine before an integration. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @LucaD I haven't been able to figure out how to solve it. It's really annoying. I just restart the machine at the start of the day every day.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yesterday I spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue on my server and I found a workaround.

The first thing I saw is that the *first* time, it is always working. So, why? What is the difference from the second one, for example? I opened the `sourceControl.log` file from each integration (you can find it in `/var/_xcsbuildd/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets`) and I noticed a little difference once _xcsbuildd finished to checkout repositories: the second integration is going to compare its blueprint with the cached blueprint from first integration:

```
2015-08-27 12:58:12.552 XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep.m:429 [XCSCheckoutIntegrationStep saveCommitHistory]
[SourceControl] Comparing checked out code with previous blueprint: <XCSBotSCMBlueprint 0x7f8928c76fe0>
```

After this operation, it seems to crash with your stack trace.
I really don't know how to solve it, but I'm going to delete all integrations from my development Xcode before the server is going to start a new integration.

If you can't do this, you can simply remove all folders in the path I said before (`/var/_xcsbuildd/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets`), so server thinks that the next integration is the first one.

I hope it helps you